How can Playwright "undestand" complex web elements better that Capybara?
I have trix WYSIWYG editor on my page, which has a hidden textarea that would be used to submit the value and another <trix-editor> (which is contenteditable) element that, I believe, is responsible for handling user input and render the rich content.
Now, if I try to interact with it using capybara, I can't use find_field:
> find_field("Content")
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Content" that is not disabled

I'm guessing that capybara can locate the label, but it's for attribute is pointing to <trix-editor and capybara bails. I think capybara expects more “traditional” form elements like <textarea> or <input> but I can't find it in code to confirm that suspicion. So here's first question: is that why capybara can't interact with more modern/exoting html elements like contenteditable?
Now, let's compare it to playwright api (by playwright-ruby-client):
page.get_by_label("Content").fill("My content")

Just works. When I check which element is actually located using:
page.get_by_label("Content").get_attribute("id")

it's the ID of the <trix-editor>, the same that my "Content" label is pointing to via for attribute.
So, how playwright seems so smart? Is it because it makes fewer assumptions about the page? Could you please share code snippets/links?

Can you share a [mcve]? Thanks.

Can you explain more what you expect that to look like? Do you expect to copy/paste it and do something specific? I have a feeling you did not read my question carefully because it's not about a single issue to be solved but about understanding of Selenium/Cabybara/Playwright internals which I did not manage to track down on my own.

That's correct, there should be two code snippets both run on the same sample page which you've provided. One fails, one works. This is the standard that Playwright (and most GitHub issues forums, as well as Stack Overflow) expects when you raise a bug or behavioral issue in code. In fact, on Playwright's issues page, your MCVE is actually executed for triage--if the error you stated isn't thrown on run, your issue is automatically closed as non-reproducible, before a human even looks at it. I suggest adhering to the same standard for most technical code questions anywhere.

See https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/new?template=bug.yml for details on what a MCVE is.
